# Distinguish categories depending on the type of publication to which they belong in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, hierarchy, categories

In my theme ('functions.php') I created a custom post type ('store'), such post type has categories. I want to create a custom template page for the categories of such publication.
In addition, I created a template page ('single-store.php') for my custom type publications and it works well, I'm just saying it to show my surprise when I find ('archive-store.php') is ignored by wordpress.
Am I ignoring any details on the syntax of file names? Is there any function that can be called inside the 'archive.php' file to filter content according to type of publication category belongs to?